# Accessing web service on different domain using ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I am a JavaScript beginner have just been introduced to concepts of web services, one-page sites and AJAX. In the assignment I got, one of the problems is to access a web service (using AJAX js) on a different domain. There is a side note in the assignment explaining something called "CORS" which enables the browser to access a foreign web service using the origin header. Setting the valuse of the origin header is, if I understood correctly, not controlled by the user.
So, I wrote the following code:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <INPUT TYPE = "button" id = "button" VALUE = "Access web service"><br>
  <div id = "message"></div>
  <script src = "zaz2.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function check()
{
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="OK.";
      document.getElementById("message").style.backgroundColor="green";
    }
    else document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Error";
  }
  ajax.open("GET", "http://zamger.etf.unsa.ba/provjeriGrad.php", true);
  ajax.send();
}
var button = document.getElementById( "button");
button.addEventListener("click" , check);
```

The code simply prints "OK" if accessing the web service was successful and "Error" if it was not.
The web service you see here is an example one I got to use for the assignment. It allows even "localhost" domains to access it, which is what I am doing (Windows OS and WAMPSERVER). 
Currently, I only get the "Error" printed in my div. I am not sure if my code is wrong, or web service simply doesn't work.
I would like your advice regarding my code, if it needs improvement. If web service is the problem, I would be grateful if you could provide me with an example of a working web service, just so I can test my code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change your code to give you the error message instead of just "Error".  That will give you more information.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Do you mean ajax.responseText? It does not show anything, however, the console says this: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: That is saying the server does not allow CORS.  To make a request from one domain to another, the server has to respond with that header specifying which domains are allowed.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Thank you very much.

Comment: You should also use fiddler.  It'll help.. a LOT.  Especially if it's a cors issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load he page of the URL in your browser. It is the target website that has to decide whether it allows your CORS or not.

Here: http://www.test-cors.org/

you can test requests to given targets and see which allows it and which not. Anyway, if a site does not allow CORS, then you will not be able to reach it cross-domain.